# for i in range без дублирования?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите, как сделать,чтобы не дублировало одно фото 5 раз подряд, мне нужно чтобы с помощью бота при добавлении 5 фото, все появились в группе телеграм, а не 1 при загрузке 5 и не 5 при загрузке 1.

```py
def create_request(message):
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ваш текст опубликован')
       bot.send_message(-10moi_id9, '{0}\n{1}'.format(message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.username, message.chat.id))
       for i in range(5):
       bot.send_photo(-10moi_id9, message.photo[-1].file_id)
```

Comment: Создайте список фото и бегите циклом по нему

Comment: Как мне это прописать? фото постоянно будут рандомные и пути тоже, так как, делаю чтобы все публикации в группу, были через бота.

Comment: Создаешь список путей к фото и добавляешь в него новый путь нового фото. Список увеличивается. А если вытащить надо из него фото - то просто бежишь по нему и все: **for fotoPath in fotoPathList**

Comment: Я не знаю путей, могу если только пустую папку на хостинге указать /www/мойсайт точка ру/TgPython/photo

Comment: Но повторюсь, мне это нужно, чтобы человек через бота написал текст и вложил свои фото и это опубликуется в группе, нормально работает публикация текста. Я сейчас работаю с sqlite3 может подскажите как сделать так, чтобы file_id прописывался в таблицу.
Как к этому прописать 'cursor.execute("INSERT INTO usermember(user_id,username) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,username))' к этому 'cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usermember ( 
    user_id INTEGER,
    username TEXT
    )""")'  и к этому и как это отредактировать 'username = ["message.from_user.username"]' для file_id